# Traversing a heap vs a BST in a sorted manner

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search-tree, heap, complexity-theory, graph-theory

Cheers, I came across a question which I thought was a bit tricky.
It stated that we have to compare the worst-case time complexity of traversing all the elements in a sorted manner using a heap, and a BST. Which one from the below is true?

1. Sorted traversing in a BST is faster
2. Sorted traversing in a heap is faster
3. Both are O(n)
4. Both are O(nlogn)

Traversing a BST in a sorted manner is O(n) using In Order Traversal, but what about the heap? I think that the way the heap is constructed makes us have no clue about how to traverse its elements in a sorted manner. That's why a heap is used for quick min/max finding and removals and insertions. But that's where it stops. I think we can also derive this from the way that it constructed, as the Complete Binary Tree is created by placing every node with key  bigger or equal to our current node to, the right OR the left (*each node is greater or equal than its children*).Is my way of thinking correct?

Also I think (4) is just a trick answer if anyone gets confused with heap-sort, and has nothing to do with an actual correct answer, so I would end up answering (1). Any wrong assumptions? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one way to see why it’s not possible (in the comparison model) to iterate over the items of a binary heap in sorted order in time O(n). Given any group of n elements, you can build a heap from them with the heapify algorithm in time O(n). If you could then iterate over that heap in sorted order in time O(n), you could then sort n items in time O(n) by simply applying the algorithms in order. In fact, this tells you something stronger - any (comparison-based) algorithm for iterating over a heap in sorted order must take time Ω(n log n) in both the worst and average case.

It is possible to iterate over the items of a binary heap in sorted order in time O(n log n), either by copying the heap and using a heapsort or by using an auxiliary heap as follows: enqueue the root element, then repeatedly dequeue from the heap and enqueue the node’s children.

In that sense, option (1) is correct because an inorder traversal of a BST takes time O(n), compared with O(n log n) for a binary heap. Option (2) is incorrect (though conceivably for small binary heaps you’d see heapsort beating an inorder traversal of a BST due to locality of reference). Option (3) is wrong because the heap iteration takes time Ω(n log n) in the comparison model. But weirdly enough, option (4) is also correct. Yes, an inorder traversal takes time O(n), but since big-O is an upper bound it would be less precise but not technically wrong to bound it as O(n log n). But option (1) is probably the best one.